# jquery not finding any attribute values

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In the code below I'm trying to change the value of the hiddenfield when the checkbox is clicked (in order to access from code behind later). However, when I try to get the value using the jquery below, all i get is 'undefined' for any attribute I've tried. I've assumed this means that I've not managed to find the element I'm looking for, so there is no attribute to show.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? I've a little experience with jquery, so while not a complete noob, I'm not exactly fluent, so there's probably something really obvious I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
    <asp:GridView ID="PROMQs" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" DataSourceID="PROMQDat" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="PROMQs_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Very Unsatisfied" HeaderStyle-CssClass="RegText Ans PROMHead">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="Thang" class="Thang">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="VUnsat" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="Hiddenfield" runat="server" Value="toot" />
                <ajaxControlToolKit:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender ID="mecb1" runat="server" TargetControlID="VUnsat" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

And the jquery

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            var el = event.target.id;
            var div_id = $(el).closest('div[id]').attr('id');
            var HF_id = $(el).closest('div[id]').find('.Thang').attr('value');
            alert(div_id);
            alert(test);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked if event.target.id is the correct element you're looking for? Although asp.net builds ids for their components, its likely that you have duplicated ids on tat "Thang" div

Comment: `$(el)` change to `$('#'+el)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to change:

```
$(el)
```

to

```
$('#'+el)
```

and `event.target` is not always the target element which you think. so the line:

```
var HF_id = $(el).closest('div[id]').find('.Thang').attr('value');
```

would absolutely return `undefined` because the `Thang` doesn't have a `value` attribute.

---

*I'm trying to change the value of the hiddenfield when the checkbox is clicked*

To answer this, i would suggest you to use a `change` event on checkboxes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(event) {
    var el = this; // is the checkbox
    var div_id = $(el).closest('div[id]').attr('id'); // returns "Thang"
    var HF_id = $(el).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(); // is the hidden input
    alert(div_id);
    alert(test);
  });
});
```

Comment: The '#'+el trick did the trick quite nicely thank you! Looking for the value on Thang was my error, I should have been looking for a hidden field. I've tested my changes to the code and this works, so I'll mark this as the answer once the clocks run down. I'll also give your suggested code a try as I suspect it may well be better.